How is react element tree is constructed for wrapped components?
consider I have a below app structure
const App = () => {
    return <div><Header /><Main/><Footer/></div>
}
const Header = () => {
    return <>Header</>;
}
const Main= () => {
    return <>Main</>;
}
const Footer= () => {
    return <>Footer</>;
}

Using App component
<App><div>A</div><App/>

When the above line is encountered in react it should create element looking something like
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
  type: ƒ App(),
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {
    children: {
      $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
      type: "div",
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: {
        children: "A"
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}

My question is now when react calls App component and go on to create elements for App components children. How are they created in this tree?
Further if we use props.children inside App component where and when is that created in element tree?
I did not try anything, I  dont know how resultant tree should look like.


When you pass children to a component, they are available in the props.children property.
To render these children, you need to include props.children in the returned JSX of your component.
The final element tree will incorporate these children at the position where props.children is placed within the component's JSX.

By including props.children in the App component's return statement, you ensure that any children passed to App will be rendered appropriately within the element tree.

What my queation is how will the final element tree (virtual dom) look like?
